# In this experiment to determine the maximum frequency of oscillation, why is it important that the position of the mass stays constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator, frequency

A metal plate is attached to vibrator. A small mass of 'm' kg is placed on the metal plate. The frequency of the vibrator is increased until the mass leaves contact. This frequency is thought to depend upon the amplitude of oscillation. Why is it important to keep the mass in the same position on the plate as we find the 'maximum' frequency for several amplitudes?

It's Q1 here : http://pastpapers.papacambridge.com/view.php?id=Cambridge%20International%20Examinations%20%28CIE%29/AS%20and%20A%20Level/Physics%20%289702%29/2015%20Jun/9702_s15_qp_53.pdf

Comment: A sketch would be helpful. I do not see why keeping the position of the mass constant should be necessary.

Comment: The original question does not state that the position must be constant. How did you get that idea?

Comment: We have to state the variables to be kept constant, and the position of the mass was one of them in the official answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I did not consider that this is supposed to be a realistic, not a theoretical setup.

Comment: -1. The question you linked is not easily accessible. You should paste an image of the question on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amplitude of oscillation will not only vary with the frequency; but also with where on the plate you are measuring (based on the diagram).

Where the vibration source seems to act through a slender beam; the force it transmits isn't equal over the entire plate.  Because of this, the oscillations (and even frequency) will not be uniform over the face of the plate.

If the mass were allowed to move on the surface of the plate; you would be adding additional uncontrolled variables due to the varying amplitudes in different locations.

Obviously a good experiment would want to remove that source of error/inconsistency, so you fix the location of the mass on the plate so that the vibration driving the plate (which is at a fixed location) is also driving the mass in a consistent way.

Comment: I don't think I understand.. the metal plate is rigid, so if the vibrator has an amplitude of, say 5 m, the entire thing should move 5 m, and so will the mass, regardless of where it is on the plate.

Comment: In an idealized world, yes. However, no plate will be perfectly rigid, and if it is driven by a rod in the center, its corners will not oscillate exactly the same as the center does.

Comment: @Saad If the metal plate were perfectly rigid that would be true.  In this case I do not believe that was the intention.  The experiment is testing the natural vibration of the plate from what I understand.  It is oscillated with varying frequency; but when you hit the natural (resonant) frequency; the oscillations increase; throwing the mass off the plate.  If the plate were not allowed to vibrate freely (i.e. constrained by the movement of the vibrator) then the amplitude shouldn't change with frequency, it should only change as you change it (making this a pointless experiment).

Comment: @JMac I don't think resonance was the intention of this setup. As I understand it, the point is that the mass will take off as soon as the downward acceleration exceeds the acceleration due to gravity.

Comment: @Michael Then there is no reason to discuss frequency or oscillations, no?  I guess I see what you mean; you could vary the frequency and amplitude to generate an "acceleration"; but varying two parameters on a vibrator seems like a complex setup for that.  I guess regardless it doesn't matter; as a real plate will vary frequency as you go away from the driving force; regardless of the intention for what they measure.

Comment: The frequency referred to in the question is the maximum frequency at which there is contact. Changing the frequency doesn't change the amplitude, but for any given amplitude, there is only one frequency at which the acceleration of the plate is equal to g, so that is what we're supposed to find. 
Thank you for your answer! I wish they used something other than a metal plate, since it's like as close to perfectly rigid as it gets, but your answer does make sense.